# Androidn Broadcast Receiver works fine on samsung but not work on HTC

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I developed broadcast receiver for time tick in which i fetch events from calender and check if current time is equal to event time then do some task. Problem is that my code works on Samsung device but does not work on Htc.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


    CalendarContentResolver ccr = new CalendarContentResolver();
      ArrayList<Sms> cl = new ArrayList<Sms>();
      cl = ccr.readCalendarEvent(context);
      int count = cl.size();

    for(int ii = 0 ; ii < count ; ii++ ){
          Sms sm1 = cl.get(ii);

          final String e_name = sm1.geteventname();
          Startdate = sm1.getCALLstatus();
          long eventime = Long.parseLong(Startdate);
          Date eventDate = new Date(eventime);
          //setAlarm(eventime);
          long currendate = System.currentTimeMillis();
          Date currentDate = new Date(currendate);
          long diffInMs = currentDate.getTime() - eventDate.getTime() ;
          long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMs);
          if(currenttime and eventtime are equal){

                      Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                    i.putExtra("KEY1", " your "+ e_name+ " Event arrived");
                    i.putExtra("type", "last");
                    context.startService(i); 
                  }

          Log.d("Event Date is", ""+ eventDate  +"");
          String enddate = sm1.getenddate();
          String description = sm1.getdescription();
          Log.d("", description);
      }




}
```

Comment: What version of android on your devices?

Comment: Samsung is 4.1.2
Htc is 4.0.3